# Llamar a una function de un composable en un plugin de VueJS 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugin, vue3

Tengo un plugin que estoy intentando desarrollar y necesito llamar al usuario que me retorna un composable, este usuario lo trae en el `const profile`

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'
import useAxios from './useAxios'
import store from '../../store/Tenant/store'

export default function () {
    const tenant = localStorage.getItem('tenancy');
    
    const state = reactive({
        user: null,
        photo: null,
    });

    const profile = async () => {
        const request = await useAxios(
            `${tenant}/api/user`,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        );
        state.user = await request.sendRequest();
        
    };


    return { 
        ...toRefs(state), 
        profile        
    };
}
```

luego estoy creando un plugin y es aqui donde necesito llamar al profile del composable useProfile,

```
import  useProfile from "../../composables/Tenant/useProfile"

console.log('hola desde permisoooss')


export default function usePermissions()
{
    const can = (permission, ownerId = null) => {
        const { profile } = useProfile();

        console.log(profile)
        if (permissions.includes('*')) return true;

        if ( ! permissions.includes(permission)) return false;

        const userId = '';
        if (userId && ownerId && parseInt(userId) === parseInt(ownerId))
        {
            return permissions.includes(permission);
        }

        return false;
    }
    
    console.log(can)
    return { can }
}
```

Mi problema es que no me esta resultando, me esta mostrando el codigo del const profile y no el resultado del usuario que deberia retornar, me muestra asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando en realidad lo que espero que me traiga es esto que muestro en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como llamar a esa data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifique usando exportación nombrada para desestructurar el composable.

Luego tenga en cuenta al importar que la función es asíncrona y debe esperar. Tome en referencia *watchEffect()*

Para el ejemplo uso:

- fetch en el composable - cambie según su gestor de peticiones.
- onMounted para simular su función *usePermissions* y usar async.

Composable:

```
import {   reactive, toRefs } from "vue";

export const useProfile = async() => { //Nombrada en lugar de default
  
  const state = reactive({
    user: null,
    photo: null,
});
      const request = await fetch(
          `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/
          `,
          {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
          }
      );
       state.user = await request.json();
      
  return { 
    ...toRefs(state)
              
  };
}
```

Importando:

```
import { onMounted ,toRaw} from "vue";
import  {useProfile}   from "../composables/nombreDelComposable"

onMounted(async() => {
  const {user:{value: user}} = await useProfile() //Nested Destructuring 
  console.log(user)

  const sinReactividad = toRaw(user) //Retorna el objeto subyacente al proxy
  console.log(sinReactividad)

  // o tambien:
   const {user} = await useProfile()
   const usuario = user.value
   console.log(usuario)
})
```

Comment: Si, efectivamente lo que me hacia falta era agregar o utilizar en la funcion el ```async await ``` asi llamo a profile ```await profile();``` Muchas gracias bro!